# Predefine routine in scala sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am recently writing scala, using sublimetext to write *.scala and run sbt in another window.

When I use sbt console to debug, every time I need to manually import packages and do routines.

It's really annoying to repeat copying codes again and again after I recompile and restart console.

I wonder is there a way to set a predefined environment to do it manually?

Another question I want to know is in console REPL can I auto complete lines by the initial characters? For example in python IDLE one can use Alt+p to search history. It's really convenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Initial commands

You could add this line to your `build.sbt`:

```
initialCommands in console := "import scalaz._, Scalaz._"
```

Result:

```
$ sbt console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

#### REPL auto complete

You could tap `Tab` key to get limited auto complete:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0.ap
```

First `Tab` - auto complete and options:

```
scala> res0.apply
apply         applyOrElse
```

Second `Tab` - method signature:

```
scala> res0.apply
                       def apply(n: Int): A
```

#### History

You could use `Ctrl+R` to search in history (including history from previous REPL sessions). Use addition `Ctrl+R` to get next result.

Comment: It's a common knowledge, but just in case: do you know that you could use up and down arrows in `REPL`?.

Comment: I know. But for example if I need to repeat last 5 commands, I need to press 25 times. It's a heavy burden to the finger.

Comment: In 2.11, `:hi` and then `:edit 2492+2` for the two lines there, exit your editor to execute.

Answer (score 4):

Also probably worth noting is that you can load scripts into the repl, too:

```
$ cat > guessing.txt
import scala.util.Random.nextInt
def guess() {
  val r = nextInt()
  println("I randomly picked %d.".format(r))
}

$ sbt console
scala> :load guessing.txt
Loading guessing.txt...
import scala.util.Random.nextInt
guess: ()Unit

scala> guess
I randomly picked -630907258.
```

`:help` is your friend.